# Problem with pdo_sqlsrv and sqlsrv driver for mssql

Tags: php, mssql

I need to connect to a MS SQL server. I use

- PHP `7.1.12-1+ubuntu16.04.1+deb.sury.org+1` on
- Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS

I've followed the [official documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac) but i get this error tryn to execute the script at the end of the linked page:

```
Error information: SQLSTATE: IMSSP
Code: -49
Message: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver 11 or 13 for SQL Server for x64: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712
SQLSTATE: IM002
Code: 0
Message: [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Maybe it's regarding the TS mode? Do I need `nts pdo_sqlsrv`? If so, how can I get them?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. It seems that this is because Microsoft's documentation performs the installation of a 17.x version of `msodbcsql` and the extensions are compatible with 11.x or 13.x versions...

I solved it by forcing the installation of a 13.X version of `msodbcsql`.

```
$ apt-get remove msodbsql
$ apt-get install msodbcsql=13.1.9.2-1
```

I would have preferred to have the extensions working with the last version of msodbcssql but I didn't figure out how for the moment.